# Special Error Page in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i want to redirect to a special page which shows detailed error message  for unexpected errors.Which solution is the best for it in asp.net?Can u give examples? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like all you really want to do is turn off custom errors in your web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

That should cause a full "yellow screen of death" to appear for any unhandled exception.  You can also use this to set the behavior so that the full messages only shows up on your local machine, but your users are redirected to something... friendlier:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"  defaultRedirect="MyErrorPage.aspx" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```